# How to implement a 1:N relationship in a relational database where one of the Ns is special?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

I have to implement keywords in an MVC application used for storing animal lines (we develop database-first). Each keyword has a M:N relationship to the animal lines.

The problem is that each keyword has a bunch of synonyms and alternative spellings. So, if an animal line is especially interesting to immunologists, it may get the keyword `T-Cells`. But the stakeholders want the line to be findable when users enter `t-cell`, `t cell`, `t Zelle`, or `lymphocyte`.

I created a database model where the actual spelling of the keyword is a separate table with an 1:N relationship.

[image]

But I have to somehow get a "canonical" spelling in there. So, one spelling is supposed to be the main one, which gets shown when the animal line is displayed, etc. The other spellings are only used for searching (and possibly auto-complete when a new animal line is entered, but this is for some future release).

Luckily, the canonical spelling is application-wide canonical, the user doesn't get to pick which one of the synonyms gets displayed on the animal line they just entered.

I can think of three ways to do it, but all three have some drawbacks:

1. Include an `isCanonicalSpelling` bit in the KeywordSpelling table. Easy, but if my code has a bug or somebody writes a quick script to do something to the database, I may end up in a situation where more or less than one spelling of the same keyword is marked as canonical.
2. Include a `canonicalSpelling` field in the Keyword table. The canonical spelling will not be written to the spelling table then. Still relatively easy, but somehow feels unclean to have spellings which are not in the spelling table. The code for swapping a canonical and non-canonical spelling is more complicated.
3. Make a second, 1:1 relationship between the Keyword and KeywordSpelling table. From an ERD point of view, it feels like the best solution, but I am not sure how to enforce it well with the tools I am using. I don't know if Microsoft SQL server even allows 1:1 relationships, and even if it does, I don't know what I will have to do to get Entity Framework to play along nicely, it will probably require lots of code.

So, which solution would you say is the best? Which one will give me the least headache in the future, and why? Are there drawbacks to any of the solutions I have overlooked? Is there an yet better solution I haven't thought of?

I am posting here and not on dba.stackexchange on purpose. I know that the third solution is the best from an ERD point of view, but I want to know which one will allow for the simplest application level code without too much risk of inconsistent data.

Comment: You can call "Keyword" "Canonical Keyword" and keep the Canonical keyword there, since there will always be one and only one.

Comment: @DariusX. each "Keyword" entry actually has more fields than just a spelling. I left them out for simplicity. But the record in the "Keyword" table has more information than only what the canonical spelling of a given keyword is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the **option 3** in combination with natural keys:

```
CREATE TABLE Keyword (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CanonicalSpelling VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE KeywordSpelling (
    ID INT,
    Spelling VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Spelling)
);

ALTER TABLE Keyword
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID, CanonicalSpelling)
    REFERENCES KeywordSpelling (ID, Spelling);

INSERT INTO Keyword VALUES (1, NULL);

INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 'T-Cells');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't-cell');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't cell');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't Zelle');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 'lymphocyte');

UPDATE Keyword SET CanonicalSpelling = 'T-Cells' WHERE ID = 1;
```

Note that the field `CanonicalSpelling` is a copy of the value that already exists in the `KeywordSpelling` table. That's different from the option 2, that would just have an independent value.

Copy might seem redundant at the first glance, but keep in mind that the DBMS will always keep it from "dangling" due to the FK.

- That way, you can keep querying the `KeywordSpelling` table in a generic way and be confident it contains all the values, including the canonical.
- OTOH, if you just need the canonical value, you don't even need to access the `KeywordSpelling`.

The **option 2** would require special handling of the canonical value - you'd need to query both `Keyword` and `KeywordSpelling` to get all the values, and you couldn't rely on the DBMS to enforce uniqueness across tables.

The **option 1** would require an index on `{ID, IsCanonical}` (in the `KeywordSpelling` table). Fortunately, MS SQL Server supports [filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx), so the impact would be much less than an index on all rows. Since MS SQL Server cannot enforce a true 1:1 anyway (see below), that's actually a viable solution here, but the option 3 still allows for getting the canonical value without accessing the spelling table at all.

---

The structure above allows the canonical value to be missing (`CanonicalSpelling` is NULL-able). In other words, it's a 1:0..1 relationship.

On a DBMS that supports deferred constraints (MS SQL Server sadly doesn't), you can declaratively enforce a real 1:1 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Keyword (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CanonicalSpelling VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE KeywordSpelling (
    ID INT,
    Spelling VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Spelling)
);

ALTER TABLE Keyword
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID, CanonicalSpelling)
    REFERENCES KeywordSpelling (ID, Spelling)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

INSERT INTO Keyword VALUES (1, 'T-Cells');

INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 'T-Cells');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't-cell');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't cell');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 't Zelle');
INSERT INTO KeywordSpelling VALUES (1, 'lymphocyte');
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply put: the synonym doesn't belong (only) in the list. A list of items is almost by definition a collection of items of the same type. However, you have two types of synonym that are functionally different in some scenarios (and functionally equal in other scenarios).

I'm not aware of any default solution, but I can come up with quite a lot of options:

- Will there **always** be 1 'main' synonym? Never less, never more? I'd suggest adding a column (nvarchar) to the `Keyword` items where you enter the correct spelling. If a user then uses a synonym, you can easily access something like `SynonymEntity.ParentKeyword.Name`. (*If it helps the synonym-searching algorithm, you could still add a Synonym entry below with the exact same word. Slightly more data to hold, but then you can easily iterate over a list when matching for all possible values.*)
- Is it possible to ever have NO correct name set up? Or multiple? (e.g. American/British English) In these scenario's I'd opt for an extra column in the Synonym table to put a boolean (`IsCorrectSpelling`). In a case where you have multiple, it becomes a case of either finding the right one for the selected language (e.g. a second column for defining the culture settings). Or you could just use `MultipleSynonyms.FirstorDefault(word => word.IsCorrectSpelling)`.

But to give you a more general answer, you have to look at it this way: **main synonyms and non-main synonyms are not the same (only partly)**. They are the same when you are trying to find a match for whatever the user typed. So as far as the matching algorithm is concerned, you can add them in the collection (i.e. in the Synonym table in this case).
But when it comes down to selecting the proper spelling, they are obviously not the same, and you will need a way to differ betwee nthe two types of synonyms (i.e. by adding a boolean, or by noting the correct spelling in another location like the `Keyword` table).

So you'll usually want to look for a way you can treat them as both. Most of the times that means you'll have to introduce some form of inheritance, duplicate data in the database, etc. You'll need an extra level of complexity.